# Use AspNetCore.SignalR.Client in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, signalr

I want to use SignalR in unity, I Added the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` `nuget` package in my solution. but in unity get the following error:

`error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'`

Answer (score 0):

for use `SignalR` in `unity` you can use `bestHttp` unity package , i used it , it's worked correctly

package link : [link](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/best-http-2-155981) or Search `bestHttp` in `UnityAssetStore`

first needed Create connection :

```
using BestHTTP.SignalR;

Uri uri = new Uri("http://besthttpsignalr.azurewebsites.net/raw-connection/");
```

After we created the Connection, we can start to connect to the server by calling the `Open()` function on it:

```
signalRConnection.Open();
```

Handling general events:

***OnConnected***

```
signalRConnection.OnConnected += (con) => Debug.Log("Connected to the SignalR server!");
```

***OnClosed***

```
signalRConnection.OnClosed += (con) => Debug.Log("Connection Closed");
```

***OnError***

```
signalRConnection.OnError += (conn, err) => Debug.Log("Error: " + err);
```

for more info You can Read Document [This link](https://besthttp-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#4.SignalR/1.Connection/)

hope that's Helpful:)